# Limit MySQL row primarily by time and then (maybe) by number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that stores input from user data and add a timestamp to each form submitted.

The forms are usually submitted daily, but the user can decide to do multiple per day.

I have to display a graph showing the last 6 weeks data, or, in case 6 weeks of data do not contain enough data point (40) I have to limit on the number of points (it could get data points from earlier dates).

Can I do this in one Query or should I rely on some more complicate SQL or worse I have to rely on my Python/PHP/C++/... wathever?

RECAP:

- 6 weeks of data minimum
- if 40 data points are not available in the range selected -> then take the last 40 regardless of the timestamp limit.

**Clarification**:

- If the number of elements in the time range is 60 I want those 60 elements.
- If the number of element in the time range is 30 I want the last 40 elements.

Comment: do you need at most 40 points or if there's more you'll want them?

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was clear. If 40 (or more) points are available in the time range, then get those. Otherwise, if the time range has <40 points, then take the last 40 regardless of the time limit.

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly are many ways to achieve this in just one query, but I doubt it can be done *efficiently*. Assuming your table is indexed on the date/time field, a query like this should be virtually instant:

```
SELECT COUNT(dateField) FROM myTable
WHERE dateField >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK);
```

I would then go in two passes, and fire either of these two versions depending on the return value of the above query:

```
-- if previous query returned < 40
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY dateField DESC
LIMIT 40;
```

or

```
-- if previous query returned >= 40
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE dateField >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK);
```

Notices:

- `NOW()` should be replaced by a litteral value that you would compute at the beginning of the process (or else you wouldn't be filtering on the same `WHERE` condition as time passes)
- The first `SELECT` statement should actually be a locking `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement, so as to prevent interferences until you get the real data (second query). Of course, this would happen within one transaction.

Comment: How should I link the second with the first?

I tried 
`SELECT IF( (SELECT COUNT(timestsp) FROM MyForms WHERE timestsp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (30 * 24 * 3600)) > 40, 
   (SELECT timestp FROM MyForms WHERE timestp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (30 * 24 * 3600)),
   (SELECT timestp FROM MyForms LIMIT 30))`

but it did not work.

Comment: @2dvisio You won't link them. You would execute two queries. First you would execute the count() query. Based on your findings, you would execute one of the two select * query. Alternately, you can build a stored routine to the two passes and just call the stored routine once

Comment: I accepted this answer since it seems the only reasonable one.
Although I don't like the approach of using multiple Queries it seems that this is still scalable, while the others might suffer from performance issues later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.* from  (
 SELECT t.*, 
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownumber
 FROM YOUR_TABLE t, 
   (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
 ORDER BY timestamp
) as t2
where t2.rownumber<=40 or t2.timestamp >= '6-week-date'
```

Comment: This does not seem to do what I am asking...

It seems it selects the first 40 points and additionally the ones that have a timestamp greater than 6-week-date.

Comment: An `ORDER BY` clause was missing, so it seems (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f64f5/3).

Comment: I think that this Query could potentially become very slow as the table grows, isn't it? I have quite a large number of points...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t
 CROSS 
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
           FROM mytable ct
          WHERE c.submitted_timestamp >= NOW() + INTERVAL -6 WEEK
       ) c
 WHERE ( c.cnt <= 40 )
    OR ( c.cnt > 40 AND t.submitted_timestamp >= NOW() + INTERVAL -6 WEEK )
 ORDER
    BY t.submitted_timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 40
```

The inline view (assigned an alias of `c` above) returns a count of the number of with a timestamp within the specified time period (6 weeks).

We use the value returned for the count in the WHERE clause of the outer query. If the count is less than 40, then we don't include any other predicate (get all rows).

If the count is greater than 40, then we include an additional predicate.

The ORDER BY assures us that we have the latest rows first. The LIMIT ensures we return no more than 40 rows.

(An index with a leading column of `submitted_timestamp` will likely improve performance.

Comment: If the number of elements in the time range is 60 I want 60 elements.
If the number of element in the time range is 30 I want the last 40 elements.